# Why I get -3 votes for this question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Drupal Answers post: [create node--article.tpl.php to define fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195525/create-node-article-tpl-php-to-define-fields)

I am new to drupal and wanna know why people voted -3 for my question .

Comment: `closed as unclear what you're asking` hint, hint.

Comment: perhaps editing your question will make those negatives turn into positives.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the downvote icon you'll see this tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

3 users thought that applied to your post, and downvoted it.

To avoid downvotes in the future, take some time to write a detailed question, which will be useful to future visitors searching for the same issue.

For that you'll want to include a detailed description of the problem, what steps you've take to debug/solve it yourself, if it's code then a snippet of the code that can reproduce the problem, error messages you're seeing, and so on. There's plenty of information in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) to assist with asking good questions if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot know exactly for which reason three users down-voted the question; the text you see when hovering the mouse over the down-vote arrow gives you a hint. In this case, I would bet it's because it doesn't show any research effort, or any effort to find a solution. I can imagine the users thought the question didn't show any effort in writing it, since it describe a task to achieve without any explicit question.

In short, the users are sending you a message: Don't ask this kind of questions; we don't want them in this site. Don't take it personal: The down-votes are against bad questions, not the users who ask them. You could ask a good answer, and receive more up-votes than the down-votes you received in that question.
Remember that a single up-vote for a question of yours balance two down-votes. It's pretty easy to gain reputation; just don't ask that kind of questions, with few details, and with no description of what you tried.